# How can I trace object creation/deletion and garbage collection in python?

Tags: python

### Background

I've written a state machine as shown below following [these docs](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StateMachine.html).

States are implemented an shown.

```py
## Base Class.
class State:
    def __init__(self,host='10.90.51.177'):
      self.host = host
      self.s = winrm.Session(host, auth=('user', 'pass'))
      self.grpc_channel = grpc.insecure_channel(f"{host}:50051")
      self.stub = my_grpc_lib.MyServiceStub(self.grpc_channel)
class Connecting(State):
    def run(self):
      # calls using winrm session
      self.s.do_thing()
      # calls using gprc_channel
      self.stub.do_thing()
    def next(self):
      return Ready(self.host)
class Ready(State):
    def next(self):
      print('In State Ready')
```

The State Machine is implemented as shown.

```py
class GameStateMachine:
  def start(host):
    state = Connecting(host=host)
    while str(state) != "Ready":
      print(f"[StateMachine] - Entering state {state}")
      state.run()
      state = state.next()
    state = state.next()
```

I ultimately loop the below snippet 1000 times in a `run.py`

```py
GameStateMachine.start(host="192.168.2.4")
```

### Questions..

The main question I have is this... **When are the session objects garbage collected?** Am I creating thousands of sessions that lay around holding sockets open?

And this leads me to a few more questions...

- Am I re-creating multiple sessions every time I return (and thus instantiate) a `State` object, or are they cleaned up by some external garbage collection?
- How can I use a debugger properly to get an idea of how many objects or sessions I have in the stack? I've had difficulty showing a full "object stack" to troubleshoot this myself.

Ultimately,
Would it be better for me to instantiate the `grpc_channel` and `winrm` session outside my state machine?

Answer (score 1):

Python objects have a method `__del__` that is called when an object is being garbage collected.  You can use it to determine when an object is being deleted.

As a general rule, if an object uses an external resource (file, database, socket, etc.), it is usually best to close that resource explicitly if you can.